# How to Deploy a Flask Application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wsgi

I would like to deploy a Web Flask Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I found a Docker Image with Flask + Nginx + WSGI that start these three services when I up a container service.

**I have two questions:**

1. Is it a good practice to start more than one service in the same container? In this case: Flask + Nginx + WSGI (development/production)

I read that AWS Elastic Beanstalk already has Nginx configured by default (besides load balancing, auto-scaling, etc).

2. Is it ok to start a Container with only Flask application? If so, where does the WSGI configuration go?

I read this article:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html

And seeing this:

**WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment. Use a production WSGI server instead.**

I understood that the development environment was deployed in production. Which seems wrong.